# php crashes with too many objects

Tags: php, docker, segmentation-fault

### Description:

The test script below works fine for 10 iterations but crashes (Segmentation fault) for 400000 iterations while it shouldn't crash.

Uses Php 7.2 on docker (Version 17.09.0-ce-mac35 (19611))
with no extension.

### Test script:

```
<?php
class Lim {
    public $id;
    public $inv;
    public $fi;
    function __construct($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->inv = new Inv($this);
    }
};

class Inv {
    public $inv;
    public $fi;
    function __construct($inv) { $this->inv = $inv; }
}

$max = 400000;
//$max = 10;

$lim0 = new Lim(0);
$limp = $lim0;
for ($i=1; $i<$max; $i++) {
    $lim = new Lim($i);
    $lim->fi = $limp->inv;
    $limp->inv->fi = $lim;
    $limp = $lim;
}
```

Does anyone have an idea why ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a new `$lim` but not destroying the old one.  So you are running out of memory.

add this

```
unset($lim);
```

after

```
$limp = $lim;
```

Comment: I'm a little skeptical, but totally open to being proven wrong. I'd expect PHP's garbage collector to address this since `$lim` is being reassigned on the next iteration. I'd also expect PHP to raise a an ["Out of memory" fatal error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118927/understanding-php-out-of-memory-error) if memory we an issue - a seg fault is a _pretty serious_ failure.

Comment: OP is using a docker container so PHP can behave a little differently in there.

Comment: The objective is effectively to create 400000 Lim. Php doesn't crash when it gets out of memory ; it just alerts.

Comment: PHP sure does crash when an OOM occurs.  And docker doesn't normally allocate a lot of memory to it when it starts.