# Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 12582912) (tried to allocate 12582920 bytes)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, php-7

In PHP 5, my program is working, but when I change it to PHP 7 the content of table didn't show. This is the error

> Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 12582912) (tried to allocate
> 12582920 bytes) in E:\xampp\htdocs\account\classes\class.user.php on
> line 216

code error

```
for ($i=0; ($row = Sql::fetch_array($resource)) !== FALSE; $i++) {
        
                $users[$i] = new User($row["userId"], $dealerId);
                $users[$i]->populate();
```

and this is the whole code of `getAllUsers()`

```
 public static function getAllUsers($dealerId) {
    
    $users = array();


    $sql_query = "SELECT userId FROM dealer_users WHERE dealerId='".$dealerId."' ORDER BY username ASC";
    $sql_query_1 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dealer_users WHERE dealerId='".$dealerId."'";

    self::$lastCount = Sql::fetch_first_row_column($sql_query_1);

    $resource = Sql::query($sql_query) or die(mysqli_error($sql_query));

    for ($i=0; ($row = Sql::fetch_array($resource)) !== FALSE; $i++) {

        $users[$i] = new User($row["userId"], $dealerId);
        $users[$i]->populate();
    }


    Sql::free_result($resource);

    return $users;
}
```

Comment: How many rows is it retrieving? You are asking the database - but throwing away the result - Why? What's the average size of a User object after you populate it? What does User::populate() do? What's your maxmemory setting? What is the peak usage on the script when its run in PHP 5?

Comment: (hint that's 6 questions which might give us some clue as to what's happenning)

Comment: According to the error message, your memory limit is configured to about 12 MB. That is a really, really small value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding php "Out of memory" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118927/understanding-php-out-of-memory-error)

Comment: @Nico: No, it's trying to allocatie 12MB more then it currently has :)

Comment: @Martijn and what does the first value "(allocated 12582912)" tell then?

Comment: I believe that, for this action, 12mb was written, not per se saying something about the total size. I could be wrong, as the general solution is to optimise instead of increasing mem (so I generally dont check into it, as 99% I can improve the code enough), but your comment is the reason I've added it to my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

This type of error mostly occures because one of three reasons: Trying funky stuff with big images, too big of a dataset or too little memory available.

You're not working with images so thats easy.
With 'normal' coding, it often isn't the memory_limit, but at least make sure it isnt. It's often 128MB or higher, and even if it's a bit lower, you're code should not consume that much.

So **it's likely the amount of data**. Continueing from there:
The fact that that's the point of overflow, doesnt mean that that function is the cause of it. It could be 'other functions' that filled the bucket to the rim, and that specific piece of code was 'the last drop'.

As it's trying to alocate 12MB more then at already has, there is a good chance it's the loop. Most of the variables in the function scope are small, apart from `$users`. You load this with with `class User()`'s. Is this a big class? If so, that's your problem.

```
// A small improvement might be setting it to a single user first, mutate that small variable, and push the result to the array:  
$newUser = new User($row["userId"], $dealerId);
$newUser->populate();
$users[$i] = $newUser;
```

If that isnt enough, minimize the data. If you create an overview with an ID and username, you dont need the whole set, only select relevant info. If you can, break it into chunks so that the memory can be cleaned.