# Codeigniter zip library Fatal error: Out of memory when i download more than 500 mb file

Tags: php, zip, codeigniter-3

My php.ini file setting is:

```
upload_max_filesize = 2000M;
post_max_size = 3000M;
max_execution_time = 300;
memory_limit = 4000M;
```

But when I try to download 800mb file sow zip error :

> Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 878706688) (tried to allocate 886603544 bytes)

Comment: Wonder what is the avariable memory on the server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding php "Out of memory" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118927/understanding-php-out-of-memory-error)